# How to add a new boot option to Ubuntu boot manager

Tags: ubuntu, multi-boot, boot-manager

My friend dual booted my PC with Windows 10 and Ubuntu 20.04. Now I want to add a new boot option of [Neverware Cloudready](https://www.neverware.com/#intro), which is just ChromeOS. So basically I want to triple boot. My current system uses Ubuntu's Boot Manager.

How do I do it?

Comment: sudo apt install `grub-customizer`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some steps to consider, please see below for my own re-search, and the steps I would have taken. BUT! Keep in mind that I haven't tried these steps myself and therefore I strongly recommend you doing your own re-search to verify that this might be a solution before beginning.

Also, you have to make sure if Secure Boot is configured on your PC before beginning. If you have, and still want it enabled, this will most likely cause problems with your triple boot configuration. Look at this link under "1. Disable Secure Boot" for more information:

https://techlog360.com/things-to-do-before-dual-booting-linux-with-windows/

**1. Creating a Chrome OS Bootable Media**

See this link for How to Install Chrome OS from a USB Drive and Run It on Any PC:

https://www.howtogeek.com/128575/how-to-run-chrome-os-from-a-usb-drive-and-use-it-on-any-computer/

**2. Fix a Partition for the Chrome OS to be Installed on**

Login to Ubuntu and open GParted from the desktop. (If you don't have GParted, you can find it in the Ubuntu Software Center)

Here, you want to resize an existing partition to make space for a new partition for the Chrome OS to be installed on.

Right click on a partition that has at least 32GB of free space and select resize/move. Choose a new partition size (note it's in MB), preferably MINUS (-) 16GB. Basically, if the existing partition is 128GB, and free space 32GB, resize it to 112GB leaving 16GB of space Unallocated. You can choose another size if you want, my first result on Google searching "chrome os storage requirements" says at least 16GB.

When you've chosen MB size, click resize/move.

You are now back on the GParted main screen and a new partition labeled "Unallocated" has appeared.

Right click on this partition and select NEW. Create it as a PRIMARY PARTITION with a files extension of NTFS (the preferred file system for Chrome OS). Use the default settings using all of the Unallocated space. You can add a label if you want, otherwise the system will name it for you. Click add and then the green checkmark and the resize-and-formatting process will begin. Be patience, it might take some time for the process to finish.

**3. Normal install for any OS on any PC**

Restart your PC while clicking on your boot key to enter your BIOS. Select the USB from the boot list and boot from it.

Follow the steps of the Chrome OS installer. Whenever you're prompted to choose a disk or partition to install the OS on, choose your newly created one. BE VERY CAREFUL HERE! You must ensure that you choose the new partition and not any other, otherwise you might overwrite your Windows or Ubuntu.

**4. Repairing Grub boot loader (associated with Ubuntu)**

Grub (which is Ubuntu's boot manager) might have to be repaired after Chrome OS has been installed. To do this, look into these guides:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RecoveringUbuntuAfterInstallingWindows (basically replace Windows with Chrome OS)

https://askubuntu.com/questions/699355/install-windows-10-alongside-ubuntu-14-04 (Step 3)

Grub Boot Repair will allow you to recognise all the OS's on all your partitions.

**5. Now you're either good to go or you need to finish one more step**

Once you're done with Grub Boot Repair you should be good to go. Grub should load automatically in startup allowing you to select between your OS's as you're used to.

But, if you are unlucky, and you're just thrown into either Chrome or Windows directly at startup, follow this guide once again but this time Step 5:

(I would prefer going with the BIOS method regardless of the author saying this method sucks. It's more or less the most guaranteed solution.)

https://askubuntu.com/questions/699355/install-windows-10-alongside-ubuntu-14-04 (Step 5)

This step is for making Ubuntu the first OS to load on startup, so the Grub boot loader which is associated to Ubuntu is the first thing to load when your computer starts.

***Summary and sources:***

Once again, all of these steps above are only re-searched and not tested by me. I used these sources:

- https://askubuntu.com/questions/699355/install-windows-10-alongside-ubuntu-14-04
- https://www.howtogeek.com/128575/how-to-run-chrome-os-from-a-usb-drive-and-use-it-on-any-computer/
- https://askubuntu.com/questions/753808/how-to-triple-boot-windows-and-two-linux-distros
- https://askubuntu.com/questions/573791/where-is-gparted-in-ubuntu
- https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RecoveringUbuntuAfterInstallingWindows
- [Setting up a multi boot system with GRUB](https://superuser.com/questions/178492/setting-up-a-multi-boot-system-with-grub)
- https://techlog360.com/things-to-do-before-dual-booting-linux-with-windows/

Comment: Thanks for the extensive answer. I followed these instructions- https://beebom.com/dual-boot-chrome-os-windows-10/  to dual boot. Now Only thing I need is add is a menuentry to my GNU GRUB. I do have the required menuentry data after installation. Any Idea how to do so from Windows 10

Comment: So, you have finished the installation of Chrome, and when you restarted your computer the Grub menu showed up, but Chrome didn't appear in the menu? Is that what you're experiencing?

Comment: @batchcoding____s - Did you fix it? :-)

Comment: Don't worry about it. I kinda fixed it by using Grub2Win. I installed it and added an option for ChromeOS by pasting the menuentry there. It  didn't change my GRUB, but I can enter Grub2Win from Boot Options (By hitting F12 at startup) and boot ChromeOS from there. It works for me as I only wanted to try chromeos. Anyway, chromeos sucks on my system as it drains a lot of battery and extremely slow on my HDD.

Comment: Also If you want to know why I switched Cloudready with the above Linux mint method, is because  [1] Cloudready doesn't support multi-booting (It used to, earlier, but they removed it when windows updates regularly broke the OS, and it damaged their dignity)   [2] It doesn't support Google play store

Comment: Ah ok, but nice that you tried it out as an actual main operating system anyways. I always do it in VirtualBox but some OS's loses their user experience when being virtually configured.